# In what way does a React / Redux reducer "reduce" things?

Tags: redux, react-redux

In the [official Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts#reducers), it says:

> "Reducer" functions get their name because they're similar to the kind of callback function you pass to the `Array.reduce()` method.

While Array.reduce can reduce 3 or 1000 numbers into 1, therefore "reducing" it to a simple number:

```js
// reducing it to a single sum:
console.log([1, 3, 5, 7, 9].reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

How does a Redux reducer actually "reduce" things?

Comment: I guess `(a, b) => a + b)` is a "reducer", that's ok... so Redux see the user clicking on ordering 2 hamburgers, 1 soft drink, and then check out, all these actions lumping together to "reach a final state" and is done by reducing and reducing? It seems a bit silly... like we play a game of chess, or we go to school, take a shower, and sleep, and it is also reducing?  It simply is a series of actions but I don't see anything reducing here. Perhaps if we say our life reduces to death, then we can call it reduce

Answer (score 0):

Redux reducers reduce the an array of all actions into a state.

```js
const finalState = [
    { type: 'INIT'}, 
    { type: 'SOME_ACTION' }, 
    { type: 'SOME_OTHER_ACTION'} 
  ].reduce(reducer, undefined)
```

or

```js
const nextState = [
    { type: 'SOME_ACTION' }, 
    { type: 'SOME_OTHER_ACTION'} 
  ].reduce(reducer, lastState)
```

Comment: if I see the cart containing one hamburger, and then 2 hamburgers, and then plus a soft drink, I see a "complicator". I don't see a "reducer"

Comment: It is a play on the "reducer" argument to [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: it can be called a stateConverter or stateMorpher but I don't know why it is a called a reducer because it does not reduce state